# Replace my MacBook Pro 15" 2009 hard drive

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive

I need to replace my MacBook Pro 15" 2009 hard drive with a bigger size. Will this hard drive: http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16822136545&Tpk=western%20digital%202.5 be compatible with my Mac?

Answer (score 4):

[According to Other World Computing](http://eshop.macsales.com/item/Western%20Digital/WD10TPVT/), which specializes in Mac accessories & parts, that hard drive fits "all Apple MacBook/MacBook Pro 'Unibody' Models (13/15/17"), MacBook Pro 'pre-unibody' 17", and PC Laptops which support 12.5mm SATA Drives".

So I'd say you're good to go.